# How to use Pyinstaller correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deployment, pyinstaller

I am trying Pyinstaller for the first time :

Running this cmd : `pyinstaller --onefile  someScript.py`

results in a huge .exe file while the only function I am importing is :

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen, rosen_der
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are beginner then pyinstaller is not that good for you, you should consider using auto-py-to-exe https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

This package also uses pyinstaller to convert but offers a gui for you.
This would also offer you some better control and let you use all the features without knowing the syntax  of all of them.

And the second part, yes it takes that much space but I don't know why. Therefore don't worry you have not done anything wrong just import those things that are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've just learned the answer to this question the hard way and unfortunately these kind of tips are not present in any tutorial.

The key is to:

- use bare python (install from [python.org](https://www.python.org/)),
- install only the modules that you need,
- avoid using virtual environments.

In my case, creating exe from within conda virtual env was ~300MB and some of the libraries were not imported correctly. When using bare python with only necessary modules the size decreased to 70MB and everything worked well.

If you want to obtain single file executable just run

```
pyinstaller --onefile yourscript.py
```

For most simple projects this should be enough. For more options check the highly detailed [official pyinstaller manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).